# Access to streams without the camera

Tags: xsockets.net, xsocket

Is it possible only to watch remote streams without access to my camera/microphone? Imagine that I only want to watch debate between Obama and Roomney.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is possible, but if there are many viewers you will not benefit of peer2peer with webrtc only. You will need a server with an MCU that dispatch the video to viewers only.

EDIT: Obamas & Roomneys browser would go bananas if they needed to connect a stream to every viewer. Just added that for clarification.

Regards
Uffe